Azure AI OpenAI Services fails on BringOwnFeatureNotEnabled, even though the form states it's not needed for Azure OpenAI
Attempting to deploy a cognitive serives account for openai, and it looks like it fails when it checks the subscription for BringYourOwnKey enabled on subscription for cognitive services.
Error: creating Account
│ Resource Group Name: "NP-OPENAI-RGP"
│ Account Name: "np-openai"): unexpected status 400 (400 Bad Request) with error: BringOwnFeatureNotEnabled: Bring your own feature is not enabled for Subscription/SKU/Kind.
│
│   with azurerm_cognitive_account.openai,
│   on openai.tf line 14, in resource "azurerm_cognitive_account" "openai":
│   14: resource "azurerm_cognitive_account" "openai" {

According to the MS doc, Azure AI Services Customer Managed Keys and Bring Your Own Storage access request, it states Please complete and submit this form to request access to use these capabilities with our Speech and Content Moderator services. The other AI Services, including Azure OpenAI, no longer require the access request to access these features.
Not sure what I may be missing here, I even attempted to comment out the customer_managed_key and it is still throwing this error.  Using azurerm version ~> 3.111.0:
# OpenAI
resource "azurerm_cognitive_account" "openai" {
  kind                          = "OpenAI"
  name                          = var.openai_name
  resource_group_name           = azurerm_resource_group.openai-rg.name
  location                      = azurerm_resource_group.openai-rg.location
  sku_name                      = var.openai_cog_acct_sku
  custom_subdomain_name         = var.openai_name
  public_network_access_enabled = true
  tags = merge(local.base_tags,
    { Component = "Azure OpenAI" }
  )
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.openai,
    azurerm_user_assigned_identity.openai
  ]
  identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.openai.id]
  }

  /* customer_managed_key {
    key_vault_key_id   = azurerm_key_vault_key.openai.id
    identity_client_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.openai.principal_id
  } */

  storage {
    storage_account_id = module.openai-sa.storage_acct_id
  }

  /* network_acls {
    default_action = "Deny"
    ip_rules = local.vpn
    virtual_network_rules {
      subnet_id = data.azurerm_subnet.np-vnet-subnets[var.np_subnet].id
      ignore_missing_vnet_service_endpoint = false
    }
  } */
}


updated azurerm version to 4.0.0 and issue still remains

This issue has nothing to do with version we need to fill and submit the form mentioned in the query for the feature you're looking for once you got the approval mail you are good you establish you requirement mentioned @NickP
